# Flask class based API and jsonrpc

Tags: flask, json-rpc

I just started with Flask after developing a rest API in django. I want to start using Flask and build a JSONRPC API. I'm using python 3.4 and am wondering how (and if) i can implement the API using classes, instead of the way described in the tutorials i've seen so far.

eg:

```
@jsonrpc.method('app.index')
def index(a):
    return 'hello {a}'.format(a=a)
```

Can i do something like:

```
class Index()
   def mymethod(self, a)
       return 'hello {a}'.format(a=a)
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction, if such a construct is possible at all?

The point being that i want to implement authentication for example for all my API endpoints and when using classes i could make a authentication class and use

```
class Index(Auth, SomeOtherBehaviour):
   def mymethod(self,a)
        return 'a'
```

Am i looking to it the right way (coming from Django this seems familiar) or is there another/better way how this is done in Flask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the purpose of the API.

If you are trying to allow clients to:
 - Get information about an object
 - Create and store a new object
 - Update an old object
 - Delete an existing object

Then you are created a API (resource = object instance) based around Resources and you should be using a RESTful api such as [flask-Restful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html). If your creating a website and are trying to organize these resources, store them in a database, display them, and interact with them through an api you should use Django because all these issues have been solved already with Django's ORM.

if you are trying to allow clients to:
  - Remotely issue function like commands to a server based on parameters

Then you are creating an RPC API and should use something like [flask-jsonrpc](https://github.com/cenobites/flask-jsonrpc).

Good luck on your project.

Comment: Indeed the application had to "Remotely issue function like commands to a server based on parameters". It's an "old" OP (2016) , we've completely switched to flask-jsonrpc, since it's the most flexible/lightweight method we could find. We needed to send function-like commands, and REST isn't gonna cut it. And things like SOAP would bring to much overhead, although we do do a lot of things with SOAP to in other projects. jsonrpc in combination with flask has been proven to be the most flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Flask-Restful](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.4/).  It gives you class based views that are coupled to HTTP Verbs and will take a bit of the pain away from routing.  The framework provides the aforementioned verb-routing, input validation, and JSON marshalling.

```
class FooResource(Resource):  
     def get(self, name):  
         return 'hello {0}'.format(name)

     def post(self):
         # save data or pass data to DjangoAPI
         return 201
```

**EDIT:** 
You can use Flask-Restful's class based endpoints and just use them as RPC endpoints if you're really interested in the class based feature (I'm not familiar with Django), you may also want to look at [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/).  Flask-Restful just gives you the means to write a RESTful API but doesn't MAKE you.

As for the authentication, what we've done in our Flask app is write a decorator that checks for an auth-token and validates it as the request comes in.  So something like this:

```
def authenticate(func=None, *, roles=None):
    if func is None:
        return partial(authenticate, roles=roles)

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if authorization_check():
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                result = flask.abort(401)
        except ResourceNotFoundException:
            result = flask.abort(404)

        return result
    return wrapper
```

and then your endpoint just needs an `@authenticate` decorator.

Comment: Yes, but i don't want a restfull interface. The main part of my application is supposed to handle procedures and not data. So we decided to not do it RESTfull, but we want to implement it using JSONRPC